# What Is "Hardware Interrupts" Process In Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, process, interrupts, process-explorer

I keep seeing it with Process Monitor software:

[image]

Comment: Usually due to driver problems, you should never see that much cpu usage for interrupts,. see this...http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/

Answer (score 2):

It's not a real process (it doesn't even have a PID) – it's just the way Process Explorer shows how much of the kernel time is spent handling [hardware interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_interrupt).

<sub>Also, your ProcExp is outdated.</sub>

Comment: Its a hardware process that runs below the software level, which is why no pid.